# Could not parse facebook oauth url

Tags: c#, facebook

I'm fairly new to Facebook C# SDK, I followed exact same steps mentioned in the tutorial, but it didn't work, always showed "Could not parse facebook oauth url". That's the windows 8 sdk.

I then tried Windowns phone 8 sdk, every time I entered my username and password, a page with black "success" and red "SECURITY WARNING: Please treat the URL above as you would your password and do not share it with anyone." Here I downloaded the same sample source code and tried, same result.

I even downloaded the sample and ran it, same issue presented.
Does anybody run into this situation? Is it just me or something changed behind the scene?

Specs: windows 8 professional 64-bit, visual studio 2012 ultimate.

Thank you in advance.

Cheers,
Chao

Answer (score 1):

I am really sorry to say I made a stupid mistake here, my Facebook app was in sandbox mode, so the url was only visible to developers and admins, since SDK is accessing the url as a visitor, stupid as me used my other account to access the app, 100% that I would be rejected.

So after I registered myself as a developer, this issue was resolved.